# How can I align text of cell at center of rectangle?

Tags: longtable

I want to make a longtable
[image]
and I want to align text at each cell of the first and the third columns at center of center of  rectangle. For example Fisrt and 2 points as picture, but I cannot align. My code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabvar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2 mm} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{longtable}{
|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.06\dimexpr \textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6.5\tabcolsep\relax}|
 p{0.84\dimexpr \textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6.5\tabcolsep\relax}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash} m{0.1\dimexpr \textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6.5\tabcolsep\relax}|
}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\textit{1st}}}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\textit{2nd }}}
 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\textit{3rd }}}\\
 \hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot

\hline
 \textbf{First}&  \cellcolor[gray]{.9} Solve the equation $y=x^3 - 3x^2 -9x$ & \cellcolor[gray]{.9}
 \textbf{1.0}
 \\
\cline{2-3}
& Long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text\[\begin{tabvar}{|C|CCCCCCC|}
\hline
\,\,x\,\,                         &-\infty             &      &-1&        &3  &      &+\infty\\
\hline
f'(x)                             &                    &+     &0 &-       &0  &+     & \\
\hline
\niveau{1}{2}\raisebox{0.5em}{$f$}&\niveau{1}{2}-\infty&\croit&5 &\decroit&-27&\croit&+\infty\\
\hline
\end{tabvar}\] & 2 points \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I got
[image]

How can I align?

Answer (score 2):

Just to say that I really do not recommend this kind of table. I'd encourage you to at least read and consider the advice in the `booktabs` manual. It maybe a little extreme, but tables like this make me understand only too well the package's case for radicalism ;).

If you must:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabvar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2 mm}
\usepackage{longtable,calc,makecell}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\newlength\mywidth
\setlength\mywidth{\textwidth-4\arrayrulewidth-6.5\tabcolsep}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\itshape}
\renewcommand\theadalign{c}
\begin{longtable}{%
    |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.06\mywidth}| m{0.84\mywidth}| >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{0.1\mywidth}|
  }
  \hline
  \thead{1st} & \thead{2nd} & \thead{3rd} \\
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \endfoot
  \hline
  &  \cellcolor[gray]{.9} Solve the equation $y=x^3 - 3x^2 -9x$ & \cellcolor[gray]{.9}
  \textbf{1.0}
  \\
  \cline{2-3}
  \textbf{First}& Long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text
  \[\begin{tabvar}{|C|CCCCCCC|}
    \hline
    \,\,x\,\,                         &-\infty             &      &-1&        &3  &      &+\infty\\
    \hline
    f'(x)                             &                    &+     &0 &-       &0  &+     & \\
    \hline
    \niveau{1}{2}\raisebox{0.5em}{$f$}&\niveau{1}{2}-\infty&\croit&5 &\decroit&-27&\croit&+\infty\\
    \hline
  \end{tabvar}\] & 2 points \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: ugly table]

Comment: The line Long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text is too near the above row.

Comment: I know. As I said, I certainly wouldn't use this. But I wouldn't format a table this way at all. You can use `\extrarowheight` from `array` if you wish, or add vertical spacing at the end of the previous row or within the cell. It gets really hard to typeset stuff consistently in this kind of case, though.

Comment: Please see edit. If you use `m`, then it will work anyway and you don't need the `minipage`. I'm not sure why you are using `p`, though, so maybe this isn't an option in your real document. Take a look at `makecell` if you insist on using vertical rules (i.e. don't like `booktabs` advice). You can improve a table quite a lot and it can help at least a bit with consistency. I've illustrated a little by using it to format the headings.

Comment: The code which I posted are cut. If you add many rows so that my code becomes a longtable, then we get alongtale not nice.

Comment: I am sory. It is good.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `\tablex`, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`, and `makecell` to give some vertical padding to rows where necessary. As a result, the table has a simpler code. Also I took the liberty to slightly simplify the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabvar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2 mm}
\usepackage{ltablex, makecell}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|X|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{\itshape1\textsuperscript{st}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\itshape 2{\textsuperscript{nd}}}}
  & \textbf{\itshape 3\textsuperscript{rd}}\\
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \endfoot
  & \cellcolor[gray]{.9} Solve the equation $y=x³ - 3x² -9x$ & \cellcolor[gray]{.9}
  \textbf{1.0}
  \\
  \cline{2-3}
  & Long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text & \\
  \textbf{First} & \centering \Gape[2ex]{$ \begin{tabvar}{|C|CCCCCCC|}
  \hline
  \,\,x\,\, & -∞ & & -1 & & 3 & & +∞ \\
  \hline
  f'(x) & & + & 0 & - & 0 & + & \\
  \hline
  \niveau{1}{2}\raisebox{0.5em}{$f$} & \niveau{1}{2}-∞ & \croit & \TVstretch[3pt]{5} & \decroit & -27 & \croit & +∞ \\
  \hline
  \end{tabvar} $} & 2 points \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can your code use with `longtable` ?

Comment: Just for the record, I posted my edit before seeing your answer. @toandhsp Not directly, I don't think. `longtable` and `tabularx` don't get along, if I remember correctly. However, I seem to remember there are extension packages which allow you to combine features from both.

Comment: It requires `\ltablex` because it's simpler to let TeX calculate the width of the middle column. The table has exactly the width of tex, and it can break across pages. Why do you specifically want `longtable`?

Comment: I used a longtale. But I cut it and post a short code.

Comment: @toandhsp But why can't you use Bernard's solution with your table? It is just like `longtable` but with knobs on ;).

Comment: @cfr: That's exactly what `ltablex` does: marrying longtable and tabularx (marrying the carp and the rabbit, as we say in French…)

Comment: @Bernard Isn't that what I said?

Comment: @toanhsp: all you have to do is to replace longtable with tabularx as a name for the environment.

Comment: @cfr: Dunno… It's getting late and everything goes so fast!

Comment: I love the `longtale` environment!

Comment: Indeed: it may be I just thought I said what it seemed to me I thought you seemed to me to have said ...

Comment: @Bernard I fill the word "First" and "2 points" is not aligned at center.

Comment: @toandhsp: These words is ‘almost’ aligned on the base line of the second row of the table. Actually the  difference due is to the use of the correction `TVstretch{3pt}` (`5` touched the line above). You can do a `\raisebox{1.2pt}{…}` to have a precise alignment.